# Assuming F(x=) # of people living within X radius of walmart is F' nonpositive or nonnegative

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

So F(x)=# of people living within a radius of x miles from walmart

First question - What does F(3) represent -
my answer - 3 people within 3 miles from walmart

second question - What does quanity F(3+h) (h>0) represent.
my answer- after doing the derivative, i got 3, so once again 3 people within 3 miles from walmart.

third question - what does the quantity f(3+h)-f(3) represent
my answer - 0 miles, 0 people

LAST Question THE ONE I NEED HELP WITH (GRANTED EVERYTHING ELSE I DID WAS RIGHT...)
Assuming f is differentiable, is f'(x) nonpostive or nonnegative. justify answer.

Comment: Ask this question to C. Douglas McMillon, ceo of Walmart.

Comment: Why a down vote? This is a legitimate question and the user has shown his work. The down vote is not fair at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are there....

1. $F(3+h)$ is the number of people who live less than  h miles past 3 miles. So if $h=7$ then it is the number of people inside a 10 mile radius.
2. $F(3+h)-F(3)$ is the number of people who live in ring of width $h$ miles beyond $3$ miles. So if $h=2$ it is the number of people who live in a ring between 3 and 5 miles away.
3. Finally, note that the number of people who live within a four mile radius *cannot be less than the number of people who live within a three mile radius* since the first group of people includes the second. So $F(x)$ cannot decrease. So what does it say about the derivative of $F$?